# OpenVPN: How to reach a specific ip on client network side (TAP-DEV)?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, forwarding

I have the following task:

```
 LOCAL-PC -> VPN-SERVER
               -> VPN_CLIENT1 (10.11.0.6) -> TARGET (10.0.200.1)
               -> VPN_CLIENT2 (10.11.0.8) -> TARGET (10.0.200.1)
               -> VPN_CLIENT3 (10.11.0.14) -> TARGET (10.0.200.1)
```

I need to reach a specific TARGET on the VPN-clients network.

This is working:

- I have a OpenVPN TAP server running.
- The VPN clients can connect to the server and get an IP in their own VPN-subnet
- VPN-clients can reach the servers subnet
- Server-Side clients can reach the VPN subnet

I don't want to brige the complete LAN-Interface of my VPN-clients to the VPN tap-interface.

I can add a route on my LOCAL-PC like this:

> route add 10.0.200.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.11.0.6

That way my LOCAL-PC will forward data to my VPN-server which probably doesn't know what to do with it. My vpn-server runs on a opnsense machine.

On my client I have enabled ipenablerouter, so as soon as data with destination TARGET will arrive on the client it should automatically forward it to the right interface.

What am I missing?

BTW: I could also work with port-forwarding of several ports, but in this case TARGET needs to see another IP then the VPN_CLIENTs as SOURCE (otherwise the service running on TARGET wont work).